# 404 error in java spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am building a Java Spring web application and getting a `404 error` when running it from Eclipse, the manager section in tomcat shows the app as deployed and the console is not showing any error either.

Can anyone please help here and tell the missing links?

**Dispatacher Servlet**

Links for Spring beans here - removed to make it clean

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<context:component-scan base-package="net.kzn.onlineshopping.controller"/>

<bean id ="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name ="prefix" value ="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
   <property name ="suffix" value =".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- loading static resources -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
</beans>
```

**Page Controller**

```
package net.kzn.onlineshopping.controller;

....Spring imports...

@Controller
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping(value= {"/","/home","/index"})
    public ModelAndView index() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("title","Home");
        mv.addObject("userClickHome","true");
    return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/about")
    public ModelAndView about() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("title","About us");
        mv.addObject("userClickAbout","true");
    return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/contact")
    public ModelAndView contact() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("title","Contact us");
        mv.addObject("userClickContact","true");
    return mv;
    }
}
```

Code below for Web.xml file

```
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- Configuring front Controller -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: How was it deployed (which context path) and which URL did you use to access it?

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="net.kzn.onlineshopping.controller"/> is mentioned, i tried removing .controller didnt work. url-pattern in dispatcher servlet is /